# Reference to an object magically disaprears? STRANGE

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

**EDIT:** Okay, found the answer. Problem was in constructor creating objects that were subject to this bug. It should be doing a deep copy of a prototype object, but in one place was doing copy of **references** in an array instead of copying **whole elements** to newly created object.

---

In my C# application I have a `Parallel.For` loop. In this loop I am creating some object, and calling some method on it. Every loop iteration has **its own objects**, so it is not a problem with one iteration destroying (somehow) object so other iteration can't use it.

I get sometimes (in some not-first iteration of loop) an exception telling one field of my object is null. BUT, when setting debugger on line throwing this exception in Visual Studio C# 2010 when I hover mouse over line (pic rel)

```
EnvManager MyEnv = Owner.EnvManager;
```

debugger says that Owner.EnvManager object is OK (not null).

BUT, one line below, when comparing MyEnv (assigned just before) to null it is null!

**DEBUGGER IS STOPPED ON EXCEPTION THROWING LINE WHOLE TIME, I AM NOT MOVING PROGRAM EXECUTION WHILE CHECKING IT.**

Just one question: HOW?

[image: pic showing the problem]

Comment: did you check ThreadID is the same between that one which run and the one you get an exception on ?

Comment: You saying that every loop have their own `Owner's` object? Or do everyone share the same `Owner`?

Comment: What does the getter of `EnvManager` look like? It is possible that the first evaluation returns null but then subsequent evaluations in the debugger get something different.

Comment: @John Odom : every thread have it's own, independent Owner objects.

Comment: @mike z : public EnvManager EnvManager { get; set; }

Comment: Ok, How are you setting it and on what thread does that happen?

Comment: I think you're SynchronizeContext is changing, try using a fixed block

Comment: A logical answer is that it was `null` when `MyEnv` was set and then it was updated by another thread before your debugger breaks.  This leads to the conclusion that `Owner` is shared between these instances - though you claim otherwise.  Please add the code that creates and sets `Owner` and `EnvManager`.

Comment: Bug solved, Owner was indeed shared between threads becouse of broken constructor that in one place was creating copy of references in array instead of copying the whole array elements.